# only parse a specific subtree of an XML file

Tags: python, xml, parsing, subtree

I have a massive XML file. However, I'm only interested in a single small subtree of this massive tree. I want to parse this subtree, but I don't want to waste time parsing the entire massive tree when I'm going to only be using a small part of it.

Ideally, I'd want to scan through the file until I find the start of this subtree, parse the subtree until I reach the end of it, and then not even bother reading the rest of the file. Maybe even describe the subtree I'm interested in with an XPath expression. Is there a way to do this using [lxml](http://lxml.de/)? It looks like you might be able to do something like this using the `iterparse()` method, but based on the docs, it looks like that doesn't produce a parsed object, which I want to use. Any suggestions?

(Using lxml is not required, but I want to use Python, and ideally I'd like it to be speedy.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the impression that iterparse is what you want. Looking at the section "Selective tag events" at http://lxml.de/parsing.html it seems like that gives you what you desire:

```
context = etree.iterparse(xmlfile, tag="yourSubTree")
action, elem = context.next()
etree.iterwalk(elem, ...)...
```

Seems like XPath could also work but I'd guess that XPath reads in the whole tree before returning whereas I'd expect iterparse to only walk the tree until it has a match. It would be worth profiling the two approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Iterparse will still require parsing everything up to the subtree you want.  It might be more efficient to extract the subtree before you feed it into the parser with a regular expression.    You might want to try writing a sax parser.  Sax is probably slower than lxml, but it won't use much memory, so in some cases it might be better.